# Alternate between hiding and showing different controls on form

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a small project to dynamically add browsers to a form and alternate them on a timer so every tick one browser changes from visible=true to false and so on, but can't for the life of me figure out how to do it.

```
 'Some Variables
Dim Browsers() As WebControl
Dim XMLFile As String = "\\********.xml"
Dim Controllist As New ArrayList
Dim BrowserCount As Integer

Private Sub Left_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'Set form properties
    Me.Location = New Point(Screen.AllScreens(0).Bounds.X, Screen.AllScreens(0).Bounds.Y)
    Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    Me.TopMost = True

    Try

        'Load xml file with urls
        Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument
        Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//BottomLeft/url")
        xmlDoc.Load(XMLFile)

        'Define number of browsers based on xml
        Dim numberOfBrowsers As Integer = nodeList.Count + 1
        ReDim Browsers(numberOfBrowsers)

        'Put urls in an array to use later
        Dim UrlList As New ArrayList
        Debug.WriteLine("Number of browser is: " & numberOfBrowsers)
        For Each inst As XmlNode In nodeList
            UrlList.Add(inst.InnerText)
            Debug.WriteLine("Added to array: " & inst.InnerText)
        Next

        'Set properties and add the browsers
        For counter As Integer = 0 To numberOfBrowsers - 1
            Debug.WriteLine("Start adding browsers")
            Browsers(counter) = New WebControl
            With Browsers(counter)
                Debug.WriteLine("Setting properties")
                .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
                .Name = "Browers" & counter
                .Source = New Uri(UrlList(counter))
                If counter = 0 Then
                    .Visible = True
                Else
                    .Visible = False
                End If
            End With

            'Add the actual browsers after the properties have been set
            Me.Controls.Add(Browsers(counter))
            AddHandler Browsers(counter).LoadingFrameComplete, AddressOf All_Browsers_Loaded
            Debug.WriteLine("Browsers is added. Current Count is: " & counter)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine(ex)
    End Try

    'Count all the added browsers to alternate between them
    Dim allWebBrowser As New List(Of Control)
    For Each web As WebControl In FindControlRecursive(allWebBrowser, Me, GetType(WebControl))
        Debug.WriteLine("Webcontrols on form: " & web.Name)
        BrowserCount = +1
    Next

    'Start timer to switch browsers
    Timer1.Interval = 1000
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub All_Browsers_Loaded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As Awesomium.Core.FrameEventArgs)
    Dim Browser As WebControl = DirectCast(sender, WebControl)
    Browser.Zoom = "80"
    Debug.WriteLine("Browsers is now zoomed out?")
End Sub

Public Function ChangeBrowser()

    Dim Changed As Boolean

    For I As Integer = 0 To BrowserCount
        With Browsers(I)
            If Browsers(I).Visible = True Then
                Browsers(I).Visible = False
                Changed = True
            End If

            If Changed = True Then
                Browsers(I).Visible = True
                Changed = False
            End If

            If I = BrowserCount Then
                Browsers(0).Visible = True
                Continue For

            End If

        End With
    Next

    Return False

End Function
```

In the ChangeBrowser() function I'm trying to get the first visible browser and make it not visible. Then set the Changed Boolean to true.

Whats the best way to handle this?

Comment: Please remove the `Try`/`Catch` because catching like `Catch ex As Exception` is a great way to hide errors in your code. It might help you debug.

Comment: I did, but the only errors I got is from adding the last non existing browser which is correct.

Comment: It was more of a general comment. Don't do `Try`/`Catch` like that. It's bad.